# Access variable dynamically based on another variable value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
const var1 = "Some Value"
const var2 = "Another value"

const var3 = "var1"
```

Then how can we access the variable `var1` by using `var3`? var3 has a value var1 and there's a variable exists with var1, so this should return "Some Value" instead of "var1"

Comment: Javascript doesn't have any good way for dynamic variable names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval()`

```js
const var1 = "Some Value"
const var2 = "Another value"
const var3 = "var1"

console.log(eval(var3))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the name of a variable as a string, you can access it by key on the `window`.

```js
var var1 = "abc";
var var2 = "var1";

console.log(window[var2]);
```

In Node.js, you would use the `global` keyword instead.

```
console.log(global[var2]);
```

Comment: That would only work in a browser (not in nodejs).  Op doesn't say what the environment is other than javascript.

Comment: Updated for node as well

Comment: Format tweak and you are golden (for consistency with the first example).

Comment: This is only going to work if you are doing everything in global scope. Wrap everything inside a function and it will break

Answer (score -1):

It would be better if you create an object dynamically and try to access using bracket notation. you won't need var. It will work with let and const as well.

```js
console.log({var1:var1,var2:var2,var3:var3}[var3])
```

In latest es you can also do something like

```js
console.log({var1,var2,var3}[var3])
```